# Simple AJAX DataGrid display problem

Tags: php, mysql, database, ajax, datagrid

I have an ajax datagrid that displays a list of items in the customer's cart, and lets them edit these quantities, which then updates the database.

It works perfectly on my personal Abyss Web Server on localhost. But when I upload it to my www.winhost.com servers, it never displays the grid! It's the exact same code! I don't know what to do, I have tried everything I could think of. Any help at all is appreciated, Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't post your login and password to your database here. Change it to stars or make something up if necessary. Oh and you should change it too now that everyone has seen it...

Comment: OH CRAP I thought i removed it! Thanks a bunch peter!

Comment: Done. All good now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: On a sidenote: extract()ing $_GET and $_POST is a very bad idea. You have NO idea what's in there (and you never will since you have 0 control over it).

Comment: can you provide a zip file with database script maybe then i an help batter

Comment: @livetolearn: Sure thing, anything that'll help you to help me :-)

Comment: I will post the *.zip as a download-link :)

Comment: I have removed the zip file mentioned above from the server as I am now using an alternative to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with an alternative as help was insufficient (but very appreciated).

I decided to roll my own PHP/AJAX Editable DataGrid. I will be releasing it completely free (no open source, just free), when I get the time sometime soon and will edit this answer with a link to the source code.

Thanks all for your help and effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some things that come to mind and might be worth doublechecking:

1. Does your database contain data?
2. Are your javascript references being loaded correctly? Use firebug to verify.
3. Have you checked for any PHP errors? Like `require_once()` statements that are failing?

You can check by putting this PHP before any other code being executed:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

That's all I can think of for now.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yeah, I did have the above code before any other code being executed but it never showed anything, so then I changed a few things around in an attempt to try and fix whatever's wrong, but still nothing. I used firebug, and couldn't find any issues there, and yup, the database contains stuff. **The strange thing is, is that this script works perfectly on my abyss webserver on local host, but just not when i upload the exact same files to my proper hosting provider winhost**

Comment: And I've already double checked requirements with my hosting provider, and they **do support** all the latest stuff that this script depends on

Comment: Have you noticed how the html after your function declaration is never rendered? That is what makes me suspect errors in your PHP. Try putting the `function BuildTable` at the top of the page? Or comment out code, block by block, to identify what is failing. I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Thanks for that peter, am tryin it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is mostly irrelevant to the problem - the bit that is responsible for rendering the table is in AjaxDataGrid.class.php

The html generated has a lot of dependencies - check that you can access each of the javascript, and css files from a browser.

I assume from your question that the content after the require_once() statement and the grid renders OK - i.e. that the script is not stopping because it can't read the include file.

Comment: I'm posting the AjaxDataGrid.class.php file now, thank you for telling me that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going wrong, because I only see "Select Database" on the page now, but since it is working on one system and not on another, maybe the error is in writing to the ajax log file?

By the way, I'm getting a bunch of `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'username'@'192.168.110.101' (using password: YES) in E:\web\username\configurations.php on line 10
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'192.168.110.101' (using password: YES)` errors on several other pages on your site now, but maybe you're just working on it.

Comment: Sorry Spiny, I was updating my account information lastnight which would explain that error. That has been resolved now :)

Comment: And that's exactly my problem - It never displays anything, all it actually displays is just the headings that tell you what to do, it doesn't display the grid, nor the list of databases or the table names to choose from.

Comment: Could you try putting `var_dump($result); var_dump(mysql_error());` after `$result=mysql_list_dbs();` and seeing what happens? Maybe something goes wrong, or maybe you just don't get any results :)

Comment: Also, I very much agree you shouldn't use extract() like that... someone could use ?db_host=some.host.name and sniff your login credentials, if I'm not mistaken (I'm not much of a hax0r)

Comment: Also, do you have an example table name that I can use? I see an available db is called mysql_9269_dbase (from a line that never gets called ;) ), but I don't see the list of tables so I can't see what happens when you do supply a valid table...

Comment: Sure :) An example table name is 'allthread' (without the single quotes :))

Comment: Ah, now I can see the html, head, body, etc. I agree the problem is probably in the PHP, as everyone else here has said already :)
I'm wondering about 2 things: where does the "WARNING: DATABASE UPDATES ENABLED" on your site come from, and most importantly, what versions of PHP are you running on your server and locally? The AjaxDataGrid code looks very php4-ey to me, and maybe the server running php5 is interpreting it differently. There's a list of incompatible changes between the two here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php.

Comment: I am running on my winhost.com server php 5, and locally, php 5. I tested the script on a blank page on my winhost account, and it actually worked. But the next day, it didn't. It's so confusing; One day it works, then it doesn't. It doesn't even work locally anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Look here is my strategy in your ajax handler comment out ever thing then try to create some data your self and see if you can get the data on client side If no then check your ajax request use this bit of code to print your `$_GET` values.

```
ob_start();
print_r($_GET);
$output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('debug.txt',$output);
```

I am sure you will find that something is wrong if it didn't work try to make your ajax call in an small scale test version, it sounds funny but it help me lots of time find out what is wrong.

I hope these help you and I don't have any other idea cause I have never been stacked more then this ....
:)

Best luCk!

Comment: Thank you for the code, I will tryi out your advices, and see how things go!

Comment: @Lucifer: Your wellcome :) and please check that there was an extra line in code that i have delete.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't seem to have posted code of checkout.php.

I can see from the starting of html which has `title` tag having something different from what is seen on another page, where your grid is not generated.

You are of course checking the correct page on your server I guess.

- But something strongly suggests your problem is because of something trivial and not actually with code itself. .. I get that feeling from

**"..it works on my local server, but fails on the host..".**

***Going by the above line, the usual stuff people miss when hosting on a different machine are:***

a. Checking the wrong page.. while updating the wrong script

b. Thinking that they have updated the script on server.. while their FTP upload of script actually didn't update the file for some reason... and the old code remains giving old problems which are fixed locally.

c. Your `php` could have errors, but for some reason it is being ignored and generation of page completes.. may be you should try `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the first lines of your problematic php page.. also ensure `display_errors` flag and related error flags on the `php ini` on server are true.. may be your hosting admin can help change the flags if they are not like they should be..

d. Your hosting server and dev server have varied php parameters or config which you should first understand.. you should generate a `phpinfo()` page on your local server and compare its ouptput with a similar page result from the hosting server.

Other than the above, you could also check this,

On the Checkout page, I see that no grid code is even generated.. so it is not a matter of javascript hiding something.. also javascript is not throwing any errors on browser.. so it could be something as simple as the grid class file itself not being included in the appropriate place on your checkout page.. or something trivial which could show up if you are able to see php errors on the page.

Because your code works on your machine or locally.. I am going to assume you should not need to debug or change any code unless you see anything creepy from phpinfo comparison of missing deps, or seeing errors after `error_reporting(E_ALL)`